# How can i use multiple model jwt auth on adonis.js

Tags: node.js, authentication, jwt, adonis.js

I have an adonis.js framework with two models (client and user) and using JWT I want to have auth on both models and it doesn't really work

I have tried to specify what authentication to use on each model and how to structure the tokens, users and clients database to support this

```
// I tried to set the auth.js to support them

client: {
    serializer: 'lucid',
    model: 'App/Models/Client',
    scheme: 'jwt',
    uid: 'email',
    password: 'password',
    options: {
      secret: Env.get('APP_KEY')+'client'
    }
},

//used default jwt for user model

//somewhere inside my auth function below

async clientAuth({request, auth, response}){
    if(await auth.authenticator('client').attempt(email, password)){
        //did some stuffs as the above worked for Client Model
        let client = await Client.findBy('email', email)

        // even if the auth passed, i can't store the token or generate
        //the line below generate error
        auth.generate(client) //says auth.generate is not a function
    }
}
```

is it possible to use JWT with both the client and user models and have the token function working on both? I have to build my own auth token logic which is really hectic (re-inventing the wheel)

Comment: Does the client model in your laravel app implements authenticateable?

Comment: @Saly3301 its adonis.js (i actually handle multiple auth with laravel) i just wanted a multi thread backend that was why i opted for adonis (very similar to laravel)

Answer (score 3):

Currently it's not possible to use multiple authentication models.

The best is to add a new field in your `User` model.

[Official support answer](https://forum.adonisjs.com/t/is-there-support-for-multiple-user-models-in-adonisjs/50)

## Edit:

*Source: [forums.adonisjs.com](https://forum.adonisjs.com/t/how-to-use-multiple-table-for-multiple-authentication-in-adonisjs/1628/3)*

It would be possible to configure `auth.js` to use multiple models:

```
jwt: {
    serializer: 'lucid',
    model: 'App/Models/UserForum1',
    scheme: 'jwt',
    uid: 'email',
    password: 'password',
    options: {
      secret: `${Env.get('APP_KEY')}-forum1`,
    },
  },
  anotherAuth: {
    serializer: 'lucid',
    model: 'App/Models/UserForum2',
    scheme: 'jwt',
    uid: 'email',
    password: 'password',
    options: {
      secret: `${Env.get('APP_KEY')}-forum2`,
    },
  },
```

switch authentication :

```
await auth.authenticator('anotherAuth')
```

*Be careful to implement the new model in the same way as the default (`User`).*

Comment: ok i guess i will have to build it myself and maybe make a package out of it

Comment: Yes or you can create custom auth middleware with user role like : https://gitlab.com/CrBast/website/blob/develop/website/app/Middleware/AuthAdmin.js (it's not exactly what you want but it's an idea)

Comment: certainly. will change my approach to something similar to what you suggested. thanks

Comment: So i changed my approach and still managed to use two auth systems. where the default User auth is fully supported by Adonis.js i wrote my own auth logic for Admin, although i had to use my own method to manage user login state

Comment: Hi @BenjaminIni , in the meantime I've seen something interesting that might interest you:  https://forum.adonisjs.com/t/how-to-use-multiple-table-for-multiple-authentication-in-adonisjs/1628 . Might make your life a little easier. Let me know if it answers your question so I can update my answer...

Comment: yes it helped, amazingly i found that approach later but the setback i had with it was i could not check if the client was logged in using the token, i do believe that i lack some knowledge on that though. thanks